# Display message in a popup box

Tags: jquery, popup

I am trying to display popup box using jquery showing a success message after updating the table row.

This is code that I am trying :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process.php", 
    dataType: 'html',
    data: { 
        name: $('#name').val(), 
        address: $('#address').val(), 
        city: $('#city').val() 
    },
    beforeSend: function(){$('#loading').show();},
    success:function(data){
        $('#manage_user table > tbody:last').find('tr:first').before(data);

        $('#success').dialog({  
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 350,
            modal: true
        });

        setTimeout("$('#success').hide(); ", 3000);
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(thrownError);
    }, 
    complete: function(){
        //alert('update success'); 
    }
});
```

But my problem is after update finished this message is not display as a popup.

This is my HTML -

```
<div id="success" title="Hurray,">
    <p>User table is updated.</p>
</div>
```

Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing this line

```
autoOpen: false,
```

From [official documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-autoOpen)

> **autoOpen**
>
> Default: true
>
> If set to true, the dialog will automatically open upon initialization. If false, the dialog will stay hidden until the open() method is called.

**EDIT**

Chage your `setTimeout` to this

```
setTimeout("$('#success').dialog('close');", 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Now open my popup box. But there is a problem, I need to disappear this popup after sometimes. Here It disappear only body part from the box and still popup header is there.

Comment: @TNK: fixed timeout problem

Comment: can you tell me how I remove close button and how to add fadeout when this popup disappear.

Comment: @TNK: that's a different topic not related with original question. Not trying to be rude but you should create a new question for that.